# "This theme is missing a 'content' region".?

Tags: theming

[image]

[image]

while creating my custom theme i am getting a error "This theme is missing a 'content' region.".please have a look on screen attached(designed by manoj kumar).any help would be appricated.

Comment: Thanks rjl your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to indent your region names 2 spaces. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2349827 for more information on defining a theme with an .info.yml file.

Also the link in your description is missing a closing  tag.

You should also be quoting some of your strings.  There is a link on the page above to read the quick introduction to the YAML file format that takes you to http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html . That page provides good information on quoting strings.

Comment: I just came here because I had an error. But mine is not related to indentation but I omitted the content directive and placed other words since my site has many contents. Now, why does Drupal 8 show this error? Aren't site regions supposed to be arbitrary?

Comment: I believe they are except for one, which must be named content.  I don't see this specifically mentioned on any of the Drupal API pages, but there is a check for it in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Controller%21SystemController.php/class/SystemController/8.2.x see `// Require the 'content' region to make sure the main page
        // content has a common place in all themes.`

Answer (score 0):

**Indentation is very important here.**
After **regions** make sure you have spaces before **branding** and the other lines

```
regions:
  branding: 'Branding'
  navigation: 'Main navigation'
  search: 'Search'
  featured: 'Featured'
  content: 'Content'
  right_sidebar: 'Right sidebar'
  footer_first: 'Footer First'
  footer_second: 'Footer Second'
  footer_third: 'Footer Third'
  footer_bottom: 'Footer Bottom'
```